# Error parsing the persistence.xml(org.hibernate.MappingException)

Tags: jpa, persistence.xml

I am using JPA and I tried to put my configuration data in the **persistence.xml** file.
But when I run the app, the error is as follows:

```
[hibernatetool] org.hibernate.MappingException: invalid configuration
[hibernatetool] org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document is invalid: no grammar found.
```

And I googled it. It seems to say I have missed the *DOCTYPE* part. Like:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
```

So I tried to add the missing DOCTYPE part. But new question comes. WHAT should I add?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="helloworld">
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="*****" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="*****" />
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect" />

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**PS:**
I have downdloaded several jpa sample projects and checked the associated persistence.xml files but found that they are all absent of the DOCTYPE part.

Is the DOCTYPE part necessary, I have to ask, because so many code samples are absent from it.

The solution for my problem seems to be:
*what should I put for the DOCTYPE part.*

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Comment: Not yet, it has be suspended. Any solution?

Comment: If you need a example with different databases, tries to see http://www.patternizando.com.br/2011/08/configuracao-persistence-xml-jpa-para-mysql-derby-h2-oracle-postgresql-sql-server-e-hsqldb-para-hibernate/

Answer (score 0):

You miss the properties-element, which is child of persistence-unit and parent for property-elements.

```
<persistence-unit name="helloworld">
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db" />
          ...
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```